# Ember sample app with server-side validation handling

Tags: validation, error-handling, ember.js, ember-data

I'm looking for an Ember open-source or sample app, using Ember-data, that is relying on an API and that handles server-side validation.

I have a very hard time finding examples of a good, standard way to handle server-side validation with Ember and Ember-data.

Comment: did you had a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/niklas/3981832

Comment: I actually found this this morning and will give it a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your API returns validations errors with a 422, similar to:

```
{"errors":{"email":["can't be blank"]}}
```

then, the simplest way to let the user know something didn't validate properly, is to place the error message next to the appropriate control in your template:

```
{{view Ember.TextField id="email" placeholder="Email" valueBinding="email"}}<span class="alert-error">{{errors.email}}</span>
```

If you'd like to loop through the errors and maybe show them to the user in a different way (I like growl-like notifications in addition to inline messages), you can also grab them from the **errors** object on the *model* in the **becameInvalid** hook. The errors are also passed into the **becameInvalid** hook if you wanna grab them that way.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that I didn't really need to do anything as ember-data sets the errors on the errors object of the model. My issue was that my client side validation plugin was overriding the errors object.

Comment: Well, either way, the errors object will have the proper field-specific messages in it. Assuming that you're validating the same fields on both client and server, and doing it the same way. In fact, it's probably preferred to let the client-side validation catch errors before the round-trip to the server. The code above should still work the same.